# Maven failsafe does not run tests in submodule

Tags: java, maven, maven-failsafe-plugin

I have a project with a parent directory containing the following in its `pom.xml`:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>2.20.1</version>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <goals>
        <goal>integration-test</goal>
        <goal>verify</goal>
      </goals>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```

and

```
<modules>
  <module>submodule</module>
</modules>
```

The submodule subdirectory again contains a `pom.xml` with a reference to its parent artifact. The subdirectory also contains a number of integration tests which run fine if I move the failsafe plugin into the submodule's `pom.xml` and then invoke `mvn verify` from the parent directory but this will not work with this current (preferred) setup (There are no errors, the tests are simply not executed).

I've tried adding the submodule artifact to `dependenciesToScan` in the failsafe plugin's configuration but that did not solve the problem. Do I need to add the submodule as a dependency in the parent `pom.xml`? Because that results in a "dependency is referencing itself" error while processing the `pom.xml`.

Help would be appreciated.

EDIT: I have figured it out, someone else working on the project had wrapped the `build` section in a `profile` section, I did not realise this at first because the whole file is rather large and unwieldly and I had overlooked the corresponding git commit. By undoing that change and following the instructions in the link posted by Gerald Broser I managed to solve my problem (I suppose just executing the respective profile would have also done it, but that change was uncalled for anyway).

Comment: Where did you define this plugin, in the `pluginManagement` section or directly in the `build` section?

Comment: In the `pluginManagement` section in the parent pom and the `plugins` section in the child pom according to the link posted by Gerold Broser.

Comment: By "_a pom.xml with a reference to its parent artifact_" you're referring to a `<parent>` section, not to a `<dependency>` section, right? Please supply the relevant parts of all of your POMs from the second level (first level is `<project>`) downwards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [Maven Failsafe Plugin / Usage / Usage in multi-module projects](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-failsafe-plugin/usage.html#Usage_in_multi-module_projects):

> When you are defining a shared definition of the Failsafe Plugin in a parent pom, it is considered best practice to define an execution id in order to allow child projects to override the configuration.

Comment: You're right, that link clearly states how to set this up but even after adjusting my pom's the integration tests are never run.

Answer (score -1):

try to call

```
mvn clean verify -P <module>
```

Comment: This just results in a warning: `The requested profile "submodule" could not be activated because it does not exist.`

Comment: The `-P` option is for specifying which profile to run with the build, not which module to run.